# Call Winforms ControlPaint.Light() in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, colors

I have a `Brush` object that I want to lighten using the Windows Forms `ControlPaint.Light()` method.

I want to convert a `System.Windows.Media.Brush` object to `System.Drawing.Color` so that I can change any XAML button background color to its "light color" on button click, because `System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Light()` takes only color as argument.

Since my `Brush` object is not a `SolidColorBrush` and so does not have a `Color` property, is there some alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to reference the huge `Windows.Forms` dll *just* to lighten a `Color`. In its simplest terms, you're just multiplying each value by the same factor:

```
private Color AdjustBrightness(double brightnessFactor)
{
    Color originalColour = Color.Red;
    Color adjustedColour = Color.FromArgb(originalColour.A, 
        (int)(originalColour.R * brightnessFactor), 
        (int)(originalColour.G * brightnessFactor), 
        (int)(originalColour.B * brightnessFactor));
    return adjustedColour;
}
```

This could of course be improved in several ways (and should), but you get the idea. In fact, this will throw an `Exception` if a value goes over 255, but I'm sure that you can take care of that. Now you just need to check what type of `Brush` you need to brighten:

```
if (brush is SolidColorBrush) 
    return new SolidColorBrush(AdjustBrightness(((SolidColorBrush)brush).Color));
else if (brush is LinearGradientBrush || brush is RadialGradientBrush) 
{
    // Go through each `GradientStop` in the `Brush` and brighten its colour
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
        Brush brush = Brushes.Yellow;
        Color color = ((SolidColorBrush) brush).Color;
```

Answer (score 11):

You could try getting the A,RGB values of the brush, and then pass them to `System.Drawing.Color.FromARGB()` Pseudo-Code:

```
Brush br = Brushes.Green;
byte a = ((Color)br.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).A;
byte g = ((Color)br.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).G;
byte r = ((Color)br.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).R;
byte b = ((Color)br.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).B;
System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.Light(
    System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)a,(int)r,(int)g,(int)b));
```

I'm not a WPF expert, but the main thing I think you need to keep in mind is the easiest way to do what you are trying is to use `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb()` or even `System.Drawing.Color.FromName()`.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I've done it like this (extension method):

```
public static class BrushExtension
{

    public static Color GetColor(this Brush brush)
    {
        return new Pen(brush).Color;
    }

}
```

And call it like `Color brushColor = myBrush.GetColor();`

Answer (score -1):

If one needs to convert a WPF `System.Windows.Media.Brush` to a `System.Drawing.Color`

```
public static System.Drawing.Color BrushToColor(System.Windows.Media.Brush brush)
{
    var col = ((SolidColorBrush) brush).Color;
    return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(col.A, col.R, col.G, col.B);
}
```

Comment: As [the OP makes clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961920/converting-brush-to-color/68027350#comment33276086_21962012) in the comments under [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21962012), the original brush is _not_ a `SolidColorBrush`, and so answers that involve treating it as one won't work and aren't useful.